# How do I evaluate which RAM to buy as an upgrade?

Tags: memory, voltage

Hello i have 2x4GB ddr3 rams operating at 1.35v 
here you can see
http://gyazo.com/b7ce756c365d94e871aa7753f2c89319
im getting 2x4gb dd3 new ones [http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00J8E8ZLK/ref=ox_sc_sfl_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00J8E8ZLK)

my question is, its safe to use the 1.35v ram at 1.5v ?

Intel H77H2-EM (Motherboard) micro

I WANT TO KEEP MY OLD RAM, I WANT 16GB, thats why im asking if i can run the old 1.35v ram at the new 1.5v ones.... thats all thanks u-u

Comment: This question can not be answered properly without knowing which motherboard you're using. It might well be able to get the new RAM working, but mixing the sticks with different voltages might bring in some instability. Why did you get the wrong RAM in the first place?

Comment: im using an Intel H77micro, i've not prchased them yet thats why im asking this

Comment: That is not the mainboard, but the chipset. Get the full mainboard type and buy some sticks off the list of tested RAM sticks, you should be able to find these in the manual or on the boards support site.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/1e47f8899307dd5b71d5f59e97ad90eb 
here c:

Comment: Added a general upgrade tip as an answer. You might want to edit the title of the post to give it some universal nature, e.g. "How do I evaluate which RAM to buy as an upgrade?".

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to complete swap the RAM you're using, best Practice is to find out what mainboard you're using and looking up the manufacturers RAM compatibility list.

For your ECS H77H2, a quick search with the search engine of your choice brings up [said list](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=1327&CategoryID=1&DetailName=Feature&MenuID=103&LanID=0). You can then go ahead and pick some sticks with enough capacity for your needs. Generally speaking, getting faster RAM does not yield you a lot of performance, if at all, so you might well just choose RAM from a major brand that's available in a store in your area.

If you're simply getting more sticks on a board that has not been fully populated yet, e.g. two more sticks on a 4 memory socket board - avoiding odd numbers of sticks - it's a good idea to buy two more sticks of the RAM you're already using.